# how to redirect to another page while sending post vars

Tags: php

What I want to do is when user goes to one page I redirect him to another page while sending some post variables to this latter page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Redirection with Post Parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865289/php-redirection-with-post-parameters)

Comment: Why do you need to `POST` to another page? Do you control this page? If so what does this page do with the `POST` data?

Comment: Is it just me or does this actually smell like a "how to do phishing" question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it with just PHP. It's possible with Javascript however:

```
<form id="f" method="post" action="http://example.com">
<input type="hidden" name="var1" value="value1" />
<input type="hidden" name="var2" value="value2" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
   document.getElementById('f').submit();
}
</script>
```

You might want to load the values and names with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can't redirect a user and simultaneously send any POST data.

Answer (score 0):

While it is true you cannot send variables into the `$_POST` array while redirecting you can use sessions to store the data and then redirect.

so

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['post_array'] = $_POST;

header("Location: next_page.php");
```

Then on `next_page.php`

```
session_start();
```

`$_SESSION['post_array']` contains all the post variables from the previous page

Comment: I want it to be invisible for the user that I send some vars. Sessions may show up in the url.

Comment: You will want to quote `post_array`.

Comment: @dfjhdfjhdf you don't need to be invisible. You need to be **way** more specific when asking questions not having basic knowledge. What page, what data, what user, what's the reason to be "invisible". So, most experienced ones may phrase a real question for you.

Comment: I am not going to tell the whole story. It's too long and uninteresting.

Comment: While true that you should quote `post_array` you are not required to.

Comment: @Geek `define('post_array', 'foo')` - Woops. You *are* required to quote strings if you mean strings.