# (PHP) - How do I automate passing data to a web page that uses a post action to an asp form

Tags: php

(php) All I want to do is execute a script where I can pass a parameter of input data that I would normally have to manually input. Its the same input data everytime so it would be nice if I could execute a script that would take me to the page and have it display the results without having to manually enter the input data each time.  The problem is the input form uses a POST to a .asp form.  if it helps, here is a link to the page I want to work with: http://www.msplaw.com/index.php?/Foreclosure-Sales-Records.html

thanks!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP header() redirect with POST variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281900/php-header-redirect-with-post-variables)

Answer (score 0):

Wrong tool for the job. Write it in JavaScript and make it a button in your browser. Then go to the page and click the button to fill out and submit the form for you. You can make it a link you drag to your bookmarks bar in any browser, a Greasemonkey script in Firefox, an extension in Chrome, etc.