# Redirect to a php page based on submit button clicked

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I have two submit buttons in a php page. Based on the submit button clicked, I wish to redirect user to different php page. How that can be done?

```
<form>
<input type="submit" value="Go To Page1.php">
<input type="submit" value="Go To Page2.php">
</form>
```

Comment: So basicly , there's no reason to have a `form action` , right?

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't have any shared input boxes, you can just do something like this, or use simple links.

```
<form action="http://example.org/Page1.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Go To Page1.php">
</form>

<form action="http://example.org/Page2.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Go To Page2.php">
</form>
```

If you have additional input elements, I suggest looking into [this solution](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/137032/657597#post657597). Relevant code sample:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="submit1" onclick="javascript: form.action='test1.php';" />
```

Comment: Actually I do have shared input boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a form for this, neither input fields. Use `<a>` tags instead. You can style them with CSS to look like a button if you want that.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a set of `a` tags inside the `form`:

```
<form>
  <!-- Other Inputs -->
  <div id="redirects">
    <a href="Page1.php">Go to page 1</a>
    <a href="Page2.php">Go to page 2</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

If you need to send certain information along with your redirect, keep your current form and have a condition at the top of your file:

```
<?php
  // You will need to send the $_POST data along with the redirect
  if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
    header('Location: page1.php');
  else if(isset($_POST['submit2']))
    header('Location: page2.php');

  // Continue with the page...
?>
```

To send the `$_POST` vars along with the redirect, check [this other SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281900/php-header-redirect-with-post-variables).

Comment: The simple problem is that all the additional `GET` or `POST` data will be lost if you just `header('Location: page1.php');`. This will be like clicking a direct link without the HTTP 301 redirect through PHP.