# How do I re-direct using PHP header function with form data included?

Tags: php, forms, header

I am working on a form site with a pretty traditional php form which emails the data to myself after it is entered then re-directs the user to a html page using the header function.

I was wondering if I could change the header function to redirect to a php page which would display the data that was entered in the form.  Is this possible and how do you do it?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281900/php-header-redirect-with-post-variables) question is similar to yours and might help you.

Comment: header("Location: http://example.com/index.php?var1=$foo&var2=$bar")

Answer (score 2):

You can, but you need to send the data via http `GET`. For example:

```
$foo = $_POST['foo'];
$bar = $_POST['bar'];
header('Location: http://example.com/index.php?var1=$foo&var2=$bar');
```

However, a better solution is to process the submit in the same page, so you can directly display the data:

```
echo htmlentities($_POST['foo']);
```

Comment: This is working, when the user did not post an arbitary length of data.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it, but you can put the posted data into a $_SESSION variable, then redirect the user.