# Why is database updating everytime I refresh browser?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Something is up with my code but I';m not sure what. I have created a very basic music library input form that saves to a mySQL table and outputs the data to the screen as well. 
For some reason it updates everytime I refresh my browser page and saves to the database. Can somebody tell me where I'm going wrong here? Thanks, Tim

```
<?php
    //connect
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_username", "mypassword", "mydb");

    //create user feedback if library has been updated
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $cleanartist = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Artist']);
        $cleantitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Title']);

        //create query statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO albums (Artist, Title) VALUES ('$cleanartist', '$cleantitle')";

        //run query
        mysqli_query($link, $sql);

        echo "Thanks, added to library";
    }

    mysqli_close($link);
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Music Library</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="" action="music_library.php" method="post">
            <p>Add Artist<input type="text" name="Artist"></p>
            <p>Album Title<input type"text" name="Title"></p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>

        <?php

            //connect to db
            $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_username", "mypassword", "mydb");

            //create query statement
            $qry = "SELECT * FROM albums";

            //run query and store result in variable
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $qry);

            //loop through returned data and output to screen
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo '<tr>';
                foreach($row as $field) {
                    echo '<td>' . $field . '</td>' . '</br>';
                }
            }

            mysqli_close($link);

        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why you refresh page, browsers asks you something like "data will be resent, are you sure?" what do you click on this window?

Comment: When you refresh, are you resending your form data?

Comment: once you submit the data the variable contain the value you enter, so every time you refresh the browser the same value previously enter are insert into database... Sorry fro my bad english...The problem is that you set the variable once you submit the form

Comment: Hello Tim, I've edited the answer to use your page link. Can you undo the -1? Thanks

Comment: Rich, no problem, how do I go about doing that? I'm a newish novice member here and not sure of what to do to achieve what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find some hints on one of these 2 answers

[PHP Redirect to another page after form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157685/php-redirect-to-another-page-after-form-submit)

[PHP header() redirect with POST variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281900/php-header-redirect-with-post-variables)

basically, you need to call `header("Location: music_library.php");` when the operation is succesfull.

Comment: Lashane - yeah it says the data may be resent click ok or cancel

Comment: Andy - Yes I guess that is what is doing it

Comment: Sajjad - Do you mean to set the variables outside of the if statement i.e before the form is sent?

Comment: Richard - thanks for that, I tried using that, but I don't have another php page to redirect to, all the code is on the one page so I just need to refresh it without the database updating, but for the info to be added to the table data displayed below the form....

Comment: Hello Tim, you can refresh to the same page. Sorry. I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh a page that before it submitted data to it, its again submitted!
you can simply unset variable after storing data to database with this function :

```
unset($_POST['submit']);
```

Comment: Hossein, Thanks mate - I tried adding the code in, but it still seems to be resending the previous form data

Comment: as a test add header('Location: music_library.php'); after inserting data. and check now adding data again?

Comment: @hosseinbarzegari you must be kidding, how this can solve the problem at all?