# passing a POST variable through the url

Tags: php

Right now I'm passing a variable through the url and accessing it through _GET in another file.

```
header('location: addtitle.php?title='.urlencode($id));
```

I was wondering how I could do this for _POST and also redirect to another php file....should I just add a hidden form ?

Comment: By definition you cannot pass POST variables through the URL. Do you just want to send the user to a different page while POSTing some values…?

Comment: what this php file above does is get form data and the encodes it in the url to another php file

Comment: Please see [PHP Redirect with POST data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576619/php-redirect-with-post-data) and [others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=redirect+user+with+post+data).

Comment: Yes that would do it....I want to set up a hidden form that automatically gets submitted...could this be done in jquery though?

Answer (score 2):

What about trying curl to post a variable to the url?