# About Redirect as POST

Tags: php, post, redirect

I want to redirect the user to some url in other website, but to send with his redirect some post variable.. is this possible? And if yes, how?

Thanks.

Comment: Similar to [PHP Redirect with POST data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576619/php-redirect-with-post-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not. :(

You can however submit an hidden form using Javascript.

**EDIT**: shame upon me. It seems it can be achieved w/o Javascript. Try to post some data to a PHP page you write yourself, which basically tells the browser to do a `303 See Other` redirect. It shall work, in the sense that the browser should re-POST the data on the redirection target, but someone reports this causes the browser to show a "really repost the data?" message, like the one you see if you refresh a web page you loaded with a POST.

However, even if it works, I think nobody does it.

Comment: and how would you post to the non-existent php file from server side? it's the same schema of the question

Comment: Don't you mean 307. As far as I can see 303 forces GET, just like 302 does.