# Symfony 2 redirect using POST

Tags: php, symfony, request

In Symfony 2 I have the following code in my Controller:

```
// prepare to render the seller info panel
$response = array(
    'data' => $data,
);

// render the seller info panel
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('route', $response));
```

where route is:

```
route:
    pattern:  /listing/complete/{data}
    defaults: { _controller: FooBundle:Foo:action }
    requirements:
        _method:  POST
```

This doesn't work since the redirect is making a GET request. I've also tried it this pattern, but its not matching the route:

```
route:
    pattern:  /listing/complete
    defaults: { _controller: FooBundle:Foo:action }
    requirements:
        _method:  POST
```

I've found the routing documentation unhelpful. Is there a way that I can have the redirect make a POST request? What would the route look like, and do I have to do anything in the controller to make it happen?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/5576619/569101

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's impossible to redirect a POST request because the browser would have to re-send the POST data (which it doesn't). What you should do instead in this case is use [forwarding.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#forwarding-to-another-controller)

Comment: This is not really true. HTTP/1.1 defined status code 307 which requires the browser not to change the request method.

Comment: I think this answer is not correct any more - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31031986/261332 below.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's helped me :)

Answer (score 42):

Latest way of doing POST request redirect (as of **Symfony 2.6**) is simply:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('route', [
    'request' => $request
], 307);
```

Code `307` preserves the request method, while `redirectToRoute()` is a shortcut method.

Comment: Great! Exactly what worked for me too. (Symfony 3.1.4)

Comment: I'm using the form builder to check if the form was submitted and it's valid, but my request keep in loop. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error with you when I used `$this->generateUrl` with passed parameters. However, my redirect worked when I tried this:

```
$this->get('router')->generate('route_name', array('param1' => 'paramVal'))
```

(I know it would not help you that much right now.)

Comment: I don't see a difference! In both ways param1 is comming like GET parameter in the URL.