# Symfony2: Sending arbitrary POST data from one page to the next

Tags: php, symfony, post, controller

My controller has just finished dealing with a form, and

```
if ($form->isValid())
{
  // Persist my data.
  // ...

  // Now move on to the next page.
  return $this->redirectToRoute('page2');
}
```

But I would like to pass variable to that page using POST. I.e. something similar to:

```
$this->redirectToRoute('page2', array('state' => 'wonderful'));
```

This will obviously pass it as a GET parameter. People have suggested using [redirect 307s and forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227975/symfony-2-redirect-using-post), but they just forward the current request along. What I need to do is create a new Request with my arbitrary message. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but worth a try:

```
// Add here whatever you need to the request
$request->initialize(
   $request->query->all(),
   $request->request->all(),
   $request->attributes->all(),
   $request->cookies->all(),
   $request->files->all(),
   $request->server->all(),
   $request->getContent());

return $this->redirectToRoute('route', [
        'request' => $request
    ], 307);
```

Answer (score 0):

Delegate your redirect to client side and there make post request.

your controller:

```
if ($form->isValid())
{
  return $this->render('redirect.html.twig');
}
```

redirect.html.twig:

```
<html>
<body onload="document.frm1.submit()">
    <form action="{{path('page2')}}" method="POST" name="frm1">
        <input type="hidden" name="state" value="wonderful" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Btw you can bind post parameters to Symfony form and render it then in template.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't seem like a particularly clean solution. Thank you anyway though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [session](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html)

In initial controller

```
$this->get('session')->set('request',$request)
```

In other

```
$request=$this->get('session')->get('request')
```

Or you can use [cookies](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html)

```
$response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('request', $request));
```

->

```
$response->headers->getCookie('request'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't simulate POST directly.
If you must send with POST you have to use:

- Native like: [cURL](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.curl.php) or [fopen](http://www.ajaxapp.com/2010/03/15/php-how-to-http-post-without-using-curl/)
- Librairies like: [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/) (warning between version 2 and 3) or [Buzz](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz)
- [Bundles](http://knpbundles.com/keyword/curl)

Check or ask about you're form.
I find it strange to have to send POST data in another route in your project.