# How to pass values to redirected dynamic php pages

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess

How to pass values by using post method to a redirected dynamic page in .htaccess file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Even if your question may be interesting, please consider that "How to" questions does not fit the standard questions for this site. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions. Find docs, try by yourself, and if you are stucked, we may help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use POST in htaccess redirects.

Maybe this question will help you: [PHP Redirect with POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576619/php-redirect-with-post-data)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the data in next page 
you can use **sessions** also

Comment: which comes close to the Post-Redirect-Get-Pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 0):

Redirects are always `GET` there is nothing that can be done about this.  Is there any reason you want to `POST` values to a redirected page?

Comment: reson is i want to hide id values and session values in redirected
my original url is like xklsv.me/viewblog.php but my required url is xklsv.me/author/title/ where author and title are variables in viewblog.php page that contain session, id also

Answer (score 0):

You can send the form values using hidden fields.

```
    $action = 'http://abac.com/abc.php';
    $form = '<form id="frm" name="frm" action="'.$action.'" method="post">';
    $form .= '<input type="hidden" id="title" name="title" value="'.$_POST['title'].'">';
    $form .= '<script>document.frm.submit();</script>';
    $form .= '</form>';
    echo $form;
    exit;
```

Hope it will work

Thanks

Comment: i want to hide id values and session values in url my original url is like xklsv.me/viewblog.php but my required url is xklsv.me/author/title/ where author and title are variables in viewblog.php page 

Thank you