# Save some data into session with PHP and submit form to WorldPay via post

Tags: php, worldpay

I have following form which I wish to submit to WorldPay. Before submitting though, I would like to save some variables into session using PHP. I don't prefer to use jQuery or Ajax if possible.

Thanks in advance.

```
<form action="https://secure-test.worldpay.com/wcc/purchase" name="buyform" id="buyform" method="post"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="instId"  value="123456">
  <input type="hidden" name="cartId" value="abc123">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="GBP">
  <input type="hidden" name="hideCurrency">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount"  value="10">
  <input type="hidden" name="desc" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="testMode" value="100">
  <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="en-GB">
  <input type="hidden" name="noLanguageMenu">
  <input type="hidden" name="hideContact">

  <input type="hidden" name="fixContact">
  <input type="hidden" name="name" value="AUTHORISED">
  <input type="hidden" name="address1" value="4 The Street">
  <input type="hidden" name="address2" value="My Suburb">
  <input type="hidden" name="address3" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="town" value="my town">
  <input type="hidden" name="region" value="region or county">
  <input type="hidden" name="postcode" value="AB10 5AB">
  <input type="hidden" name="country" value="GB">
  <input type="hidden" name="tel" value="0123456789">
  <input type="hidden" name="email" value="demo@worldpay.com">
</form>
```

Comment: Set the form action to your own script, store variables there, then redirect further (with the post data) to worldpay. Don't think a browser would 'like' this though.. I would use AJAX.

Comment: About redirecting with post data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576619/php-redirect-with-post-data

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to run `session_start()` first thing, before any headers have been sent.  Then putting a value in the the session is as easy as:

```
$_SESSION['instId'] = $_POST['instId']
```

Do that for every form value and it will be saved and accesible to the session array as long as that session is valid.

**You'll need to point your form to your own script first for this to work.**

After that you can do a request using `curl` to send the post data on to `https://secure-test.worldpay.com/wcc/purchase` like so:

```
//set POST variables
$url = 'https://secure-test.worldpay.com/wcc/purchase';
$fields = array(
    'instId' => urlencode($_POST['instId']),
    ... other fields
);

$postVars = http_build_query($fields);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postVars);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Did that answer the question?  Was it more about how to save it to a session first, or how to send this to another location afterward?

Comment: His form does not point to his own script, would be difficult

Comment: Could you please paste me an example about posting with curl?

Comment: I completed the fields above and tried the script however I get following error on WorldPay page:

Secure Payment Page
Sorry, there was a problem processing your payment:
The information sent from the merchant's site is invalid or incomplete. Please send the following information to the merchant:

The transaction cannot be processed for one or more of the following reasons:
The merchant account is suspended.
The order currency selected is not supported.
The authorisation mode is incorrect.
Test mode is unavailable.
The installation is not live.
Server ID mm2imscs4p (WPReq-77780)

Comment: I don't know anything about WorldPay specifically.  Can you talk to tech support there, or find an API page to get the details on how to send them a POST request?