# redirect user to another page

Tags: php

I have this form :

I want to know if there is some way that when a user choose `directeur` from `niveau option field` to be redirected to the `directeur's page`, and if he is choose some other value he will be redirected to this value's page.

I know the method using `JavaScript` but I have to work only with `PHP`, and to do all manipulation on that form in the same page where the page is.

I tried this :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
   {
      if($_POST['niveau'] == 'directeur')
          header('Location: directeur.php');

   }
```

but this will redirect the user to the page without the `$_POST` values.
I know that there I can send some values with the url and retreive them use `$_GET` but I have to use only `$_POST`.

so is there any other method to do that ?

Comment: You are trying to set post data on a PHP redirect. This already exists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576619/php-redirect-with-post-data

Comment: Rather than POST, this is a job for `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use [`$_SESSION`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php):

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if($_POST['niveau'] == 'directeur')
        $_SESSION['info'] = $_POST;
        header('Location: directeur.php');
    }
}
```

And in directeur.php:

```
session_start();
$niveau = $_SESSION['info'];
```