# POST variable to another page while redirecting - php

Tags: php

I am redirecting the user back to login page if the login inputs arenot correct.

```
$sql = "select * from Driver where username=$username and pwd=$pwd";
$driver = mysql_query($sql);

if(!$driver){
  header("Location: http://domain.de/login.php");
  exit();
}
```

can i also pass message like `"sorry, username isnot correct"` to login page?

i dont want to use session. get isnot the option here

Comment: @Kevin, how? can you please say more words?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php should help you. When you append it to the URL. Make sure you use urldecode() on the other side.

Comment: @Kevin, thanks. working now. but can i also POST the variable?

Comment: You can, but it gets messy. See this question for a detailed explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576619/php-redirect-with-post-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do it like

```
header("Location: http://domain.de/login.php?error=username");
```

and do on the other page

```
if ($_GET['error'] == 'username') {
    echo 'Sorry, username is not correct!';
}
```

EDIT:
Watch out for SQL injection also

Comment: simple: i have big message and i dont want to put it to url

Comment: That's why you just use ?error=username and in the other page you use if else statements to show the big message ;)

Answer (score 1):

You may add get paramet to location header or save message flag in session. Like this:

```
 $sql = "select * from Driver where username=$username and pwd=$pwd";
 $driver = mysql_query($sql);

 if(!$driver){
     header("Location: http://domain.de/login.php?wasredirect=1");
     exit();
 }

 //////// In login.php

 if (isset($_GET['wasredirect'])) {
     echo "sorry, username isnot correct";
 }
```

Or this:

```
     $sql = "select * from Driver where username=$username and pwd=$pwd";
 $driver = mysql_query($sql);

 if(!$driver){
     header("Location: http://domain.de/login.php");
     if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
         session_start();
     }
     $_SESSION['redirect'] = true;
     exit();
 }

 //////// In login.php

 if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
     session_start();
 }
 $_SESSION['redirect'] = true;
 if (isset($_SESSION['redirect']) &&$_SESSION['redirect'] ) {
     echo "sorry, username isnot correct";
     unset($_SESSION['redirect']);
 }
```

Comment: i dont want to save into session. this is just a 2 second message and it doesnot have to be saved into session

Comment: You may delete value from session after "use", like in example, or add get paramter

Answer (score 1):

For simply giving away a message, you can add it to the URL.

```
header("Location: http://domain.de/login.php?e=1234");
```

I recommend using error codes instead of full-length messages for better flexibility.

Note, how ever, that doing it right would require to implement a MVC pattern and then internally load the routing of the error page. But that might be too much for a small script.

I know you don´t ant feedback to your query. No need to worry, unless you are clueless about what SQL injection means.

Best regard

Zsolt

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is to load that login.php page as a part (the view) of the current script (the controller) and set a variable with the value of the message. Something like:

```
if(!$driver){
$message = "Sorry, username isnot correct";
} 
else {
$message = "Whatever";
}
include('login.php');
```

$message will be available for you inside login.php script.

Answer (score -3):

Change the query to:

```
$sql = "select * from `Driver` where `username`='$username' and `pwd`='$pwd'";
```

Note the backticks and single quotes

Comment: this is not the quuestion, my query is fine

Comment: Strings in sql query which are not in quotations can make problem

Comment: in case the variable get a value as reserved mysql words, like `select` or `order`