# Redirecting to another domain with post data, http_redirect alternative

Tags: php

I need to make a redirect from siteA to siteB, not just a redirect, but also send $_POST data to siteB.

After some research I found `http_redirect()` function, which does what I was looking for. Unfortunately I can't use this function so I am looking for an alternative which would do the same thing.

Also tried `header('Location: http://siteB.com', TRUE, 307);` and redirecting with `$.post` (after some research I found out that $.post cant rederect with post values)

Any suggestions?

Edit:

Made it work by just adding siteB to the forms action parameter.. It sends post values to that url..

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Redirect with POST data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576619/php-redirect-with-post-data)

Comment: `$.post` jQuery method??

Comment: $.post jQuery wont work, it cant rederect and sent post data (to my understanding).

Comment: Have you looked at Barmars link? You'll need to pint out a form with the values inserted into hidden inputs, then auto submit the form with Javascript.