# curl not redirecting as expected

Tags: php, curl

Any idea why this function is not redirecting to paypal.com and instead I am staying on the same page? curl is activated on the server, safe mode is off and openbasedir is turned off too.

```
function curl_post($url, array $post = NULL, array $options = array())
{
    $defaults = array(
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT => 1,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE => 1,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 4,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($post)
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, ($options + $defaults));
    if( ! $result = curl_exec($ch))
    {
        trigger_error(curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
curl_post("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr",$_POST);
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: AS far as I know, curl just makes http requests. It doesn't redirect, or act as any kind of web browser.

Answer (score 3):

After you make curl request:

```
foreach ($parameters as $key => $value) {
    $requestParams[] = $key . '=' . $value;
}
$requestParams = implode ('&', $requestParams);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestParams);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

You should get exact url, to know where you should be redirected:

```
$location = curl_getinfo($ch)['redirect_url'];
```

And then redirect:

```
header('Location: '. $location);
```

Answer (score 0):

cURL is just a library for initiating and firing HTTP and FTP requests.
Your code just sends a *HTTP POST* request to the PayPal server.

In order to redirect the user, send a *Location* header (before any output!):

```
header('Location: https://www.paypal.com/...');
```

Comment: Could I send the post information as well? Could you use it with my code?

Comment: @JimmyHendrikz This is not possible, see here for further information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576619/php-redirect-with-post-data