# How to pass a form value to next page in other form

Tags: php, forms

How to pass a form value to next page in other form?

I have this code in the :

```
<form action="confirm.php" method="post">
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email">
</form>
```

Now I want that in confirm.php to put some hidden input fields with this values, I tried this code:

```
<form action="nextpage.php" method="post">

//some other input fields...

<input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="<?php $_POST['firstname']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="<?php $_POST['lastname']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php $_POST['email']?>">
</form>
```

And so on in other 2 pages, and in the last page I want to email all this fields, I tried PHP _SESSION, but no luck with that, so I think that this can be more easier for me!

And something else I forgot to tell, on the second page (nextpage.php) action form variable I refer to a file that use this code:

```
<?php
header('Location: dear-'.$_POST['firstname'].'.php');
?>

<html>
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $_POST['firstname']?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $_POST['lastname']?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']?>">
</form>
</html>
```

In this case how to pass this values (firstname, lastname and email) on the next page ? I use that because I want to generate a page like this www.site.com/dear-name.php

Comment: You need to echo the value <?php echo $_POST['firstname']; ?>

Comment: I believe this post also may help;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576619/php-redirect-with-post-data

Comment: just tried, but when I send the email I do not get the first values

Comment: keep the values in the `session` that is more helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to `echo` your variable.

```
<input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $_POST['firstname']; ?>">
```

---

**Update:**

You have two choices :

1. Store your data to `session` and retrieve to another page.
2. Pass your data using `query string`.

   ```
   header('Location: dear-'.$_POST['firstname'].'.php?firstname='.$_POST['firstname'].'&lastname='.$_POST['lastname'].'&email='.$_POST['email']);
   ```

Comment: Something else, how to store and retrieve data with `session`, I ment get and post with that function?

Answer (score 2):

Try this in confirm.php

```
<form action="nextpage.php" method="post">

//some other input fields...

<input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $_POST['firstname']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $_POST['lastname']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']?>">
</form>
```

Comment: In this case, you can pass as parameters through url.

Answer (score 0):

use **echo**:

```
<input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $_POST['firstname']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $_POST['lastname']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>">
```

and if this still not working, `isset()` your post variables:

```
if(isset($_POST['firstname'],$_POST['lastname'],$_POST['email'])) {
   $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
   $lastname  = $_POST['lastname'];
   $email     = $_POST['email'];

   echo '<input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="$firstname">';
   echo '<input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="$lastname">';
   echo '<input type="hidden" name="email" value="$email">';
}
```

Comment: I get this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /public_html/test/dear.php on line 4. The line 4 is this code: if(isset($_POST['firstname'],$_POST['lastname'],$_POST['email'])) {

Answer (score 0):

In your input text field, value is empty because of `echo` is missing. You need to add `echo` to print the value in your form. So that it can be sent into another page.

Answer (score 0):

The second option is that you can use `session_start()` in top of each page.
and store the value of the variable in your session.

```
$_SESSION['name'] = "value_of_session"// in your case that is POST data
```

and this can be used in next page you need not to include `hidden` fields.

the most important thing is that You must write

```
<?php session_start()  ?> // in each(you've three) page.
```