# Redirect with method post

Tags: php, yii2

My redirect:

```
public function actionLogout()
{
    Yii::$app->user->logout();

    $cookies = Yii::$app->response->cookies;
    $cookies->remove('isBackendLogin');
    unset($cookies['isBackendLogin']);

    if ( !strpos(Url::current(), 'backend') )
    {
        //POST Method sent
        return $this->redirect(['backend/user/auth/logout']);
    }
    return $this->goHome();
}
```

but logout require post data-method.

Is there any way to redirect to this page?

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576619/php-redirect-with-post-data

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden fields on logout page, and submit the form automaticly with some javascript when the user hits that page.

Edit:
Just saw the tag of a framework. Sageth, gave a answer for your framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters with the [redirect](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html#redirect()-detail) if you add parameters to the `url` array.

```
return $this->redirect(['/backend/user/auth/logout', 
                        'key' => 'value',
                        'anotherPostKey' => 'anotherPostValue',
                       ]);
```

Comment: In Your example, key and anotherPostKey will be sent by GET method

Comment: Oh, I see.
It seems that Yii2 cant redirect with POST, but you have a users global variable if you want to store data with the user session. You want more information about that?

Comment: Yes, please. My problem is that i have two separate session for frontend and backend. If i logout in frontend i also must logout in backend.
[code]public function actionLogout()
 {
  Yii::$app->user->logout();

  $cookies = Yii::$app->response->cookies;
  $cookies->remove('isBackendLogin');
  unset($cookies['isBackendLogin']);

  if ( !strpos(Url::current(), 'backend') )
  {
   // redirect this
   return $this->redirect_post( Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(['/backend/user/auth/logout']), [] );
  }
  return $this->goHome();
 }[/code]

Comment: Edit your original question with this code to find a better ansewer :D

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to achieve this.

1. Change the logout method allow rule from POST to GET & POST in access rules

   OR
2. To redirect with POST method, render a page which will have form with POST method type and action set to logout page. Call the form submit using javascript on page load.