# Redirect with parameters without using query string

Tags: node.js, express

I need to perform a redirect from a route to another route and pass some data to the latter route. I'm using query strings to pass data between routes, but I'd like to avoid this.

#### My current solution

I'm using `res.redirect` and `url.format()` to pass the data between routes as a query string.

Current code:

```
app.get('x-foo', (req, res) => {
  const foo = '1234';

  res.redirect(url.format({
     pathname: 'x-bar',
     query: {
       foo: foo
     }
   }));
})

app.get('x-bar', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.query.foo); // logs '1234'
  res.render(...some page)
});
```

#### Why I'd like to avoid it

I'd like to avoid this method because I don't want the query string to appear in the user's browser.

Is there any other way to do this that *doesn't* involve query strings?

Comment: is the 2nd route in the same domain as the 1st? if o you can set httpOnly secure cookies to be picked by the 2nd route and then removed. if not this a similar thread although different technology it is the same situation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576619/php-redirect-with-post-data

Comment: That's still a bit convoluted. Isn't there a way to do this by Express routing?

Comment: Are you using sessions? Because this is [basically] as typical a scenario as it gets.

Comment: @BradChristie No.

Comment: @BradChristie I'm just thinking I might be able to get away with this by using the `body` instead.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Not for a GET request... Either way, it's basically either a) Use queryString, b) use session, c) use cookie, d) Use something more elaborate like a local file or something else that wouldn't be thread/request safe