# Laravel 302 redirection when I do a POST

Tags: php, laravel

I am having a problem with Laravel.

I try to do a POST with JQuery to my Controller, but when I do that, I recieve a HTTP 302 code (found), and after that It creates a GET to the same controller URL.

Here there is my code:

**WizardController.php**

```
class WizardController extends Controller
{
    public function saveForm(Request $request) {
        $data = $request->data;
        error_log(print_r($data, true));
        return response()->json(['message' => 'test']);
    }
}
```

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'wizard', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function(){
    Route::post('create', 'WizardController@saveForm');
})
```

**Wizard.html**

```
<script>
    var token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
    $.ajax('wizard/create', function() {
        method: 'POST',
        data:    {'data' : 'test'},
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
     });
</script>
```

I even cannot see the log in my controller. Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: `return  return` ???

Comment: why do u have double return ` return  return response()->json(['message' => 'test']);`

Comment: You have an excess of returns.

Comment: sorry, guys, in the code I don't have that much returns... it was only a copy paste problem when I created the post in stackoverflow, I just updated the post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Redirect with POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576619/php-redirect-with-post-data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have middleware `'auth'` for your route. You should investigate a bit on it and you'll understand why doesn't it work.

The point is that `'auth'` middleware requires cookies to work correctly, while you have it empty when you're have Ajax request. Why does it give you 302 and not 401? You should look into your authentication handler for any custom logic on that.

What to do? Implement [JWT auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) or [stateless authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#stateless-http-basic-authentication)!

Answer (score 1):

OK problem solved...

My problem was in routes/web.php, I declared that route inside a Route group, which has two other customized middlewares.

One of those middleware was making me that wrong redirection.

Comment: Same issue, same solution :)