# How to intercept auto submit form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml

My issue is I need to POST XML data to a payment gateway.

I've tried to follow the answer from [PHP Redirect with POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576619/php-redirect-with-post-data), but I need to intercept the submit to manipulate the data.

So, I've tried the following:

```
<html>
<form id="myForm" action="<?php echo $url; ?>" method="post">

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready (function () {
    document.getElementById('myForm').submit();

    $('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
        console.log('A');

        e.preventDefault();

        alert("a");

        $.post("<?php echo $url; ?>", {'data': formxml}, function (data) {
            // callback logic
        });
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

However, it doesn't work as I expected it to be.

When I do the `document.getElementById('myForm').submit()`, I expected the `$('#myForm').submit` will intercept it and I can do data validation.

How should I proceed with it in order to achieve my expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick pointer - Javascript is interpreted line by line. Meaning line one gets executed before line 2.

In your case, the following line:

```
document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
```

is getting executed before:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
    console.log('A');

    e.preventDefault();

    alert("a");

    $.post("<?php echo $url; ?>", {'data': formxml}, function (data) {
        // callback logic
    });
});
```

Thereby resulting in the `submit()` to be triggered much before your handler has had a chance to be bound to the form.

Try interchanging them. The following code works:

```
<html>
<form id="myForm" action="<?php echo $url; ?>" method="post">

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready (function () {
    $('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
        console.log('A');

        e.preventDefault();

        alert("a");

        $.post("<?php echo $url; ?>", {'data': formxml}, function (data) {
            // callback logic
        });
    });

    $('#myForm').submit();
});
</script>
</html>
```

---

Let me know if that is not the result you were expecting.

Comment: This is the result that I am expecting. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using vanilla JavaScript to trigger your submit while your event listener is set up by jQuery. Change

```
document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
```

to

```
$('#myForm').submit();
```

and you should see the expected result.