# Yii2: How to redirect with POST method?

Tags: php, redirect, post, get, yii2

I have the Yii2 **delete action** in a controller and I need to redirect to `index.php` with the `id` variable by POST method. This is how I do it with GET method:

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $this->findModel($id)->delete();

    return $this->redirect(['index?id=' . $id]);
}
```

How can I redirect using the POST method?

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576619/php-redirect-with-post-data ?

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa I prefer the redirect Yii2 method.

Comment: If you want to redirect with post data, you could always render an intermediate view, in which you make a form that send the post data.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot redirect using the `POST` method as it is a shortcut to  `Response::redirect()` which is defined as

> This method adds a "Location" header to the current response.

What you can do alternatively to achieve the desired effect is to call the `actionDelete` via ajax and response a `success` or `failure` from the action to the ajax call where you can submit the `id` using the `$.post()`.

For example consider the following code where we have a button on which we bind the `click` event and get the id of the record that we need to delete, it can either be inside a hidden field, we send the request to the `actionDelete` and if all is ok we submit the id using `$.post()`.

```
$js = <<< JS

$("#delete").on('click',function(){
    var id = $("#record_id").val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'/controller/action',
        method:'post',
        data:{id:id},
        success:function(data){
            if(data.success){
                $.post('/controller/action',{id:data.id});
            }else{
                alert(response.message);
            }
        }
    });
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($js,\yii\web\View::POS_READY);
echo Html::hiddenInput('record_id', 1, ['id'=>'record_id']);
echo Html::button('Delete',['id'=>'delete']);
```

Your `actiondelete()` should look like below

```
public function actionDelete(){

    $response = ['success'=>false];

    $id = Yii::$app->request->post('id');

    Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

    try{
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();
        $response['success'] = true;
        $response['id'] = $id;
    }catch(\Exception $e){
        $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible, see below link:

https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/redirect-with-post/36684/2