# EuPlatesc payment integration

Tags: plugins, sylius, payum

EuPlatesc is a Romanian provider for online payments.
I want to integrate this in Sylius platform as a plugin. I've reached the phase where I'm handling the step after checkout that reaches CaptureAction.php.

However EuPlatesc works with a POST request made to a secure url, similar to this description [PHP Redirect with POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576619/php-redirect-with-post-data).

Is it possible to implement this kind of behavior in Sylius ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Payum\Core\Reply\HttpPostRedirect` class, which makes a POST request and redirects user to payment processor page. The example of it usage you can find in [Be2Bill gateway](https://github.com/Payum/Be2Bill/blob/master/Action/CaptureOffsiteAction.php#L67)

Comment: yes, I've found it by looking at gopay plugin just this morning, thanks