# Redirect To another Page using and use POST to send DATA

Tags: php, redirect, post, get

I have a page which `executes` some queries and after completing

```
header('Location: '.url_money.'SyncComp.php?Comp=YES');
```

It gets redirected to other page. But I want to send it through  HTTP Post

This `?Comp=YES` should not be appended to URL instead send by HTTP Post.

I cannot use `onLoad` of `JavaScript` as it would directly call the function before executing the `sql queries`

Comment: send it through _POST_ what?

Comment: "?Comp=YES" This should not be appended but should be send by post

Comment: See this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865289/php-redirection-with-post-parameters).  The accepted answer has some good information.

Comment: It Should be posted like SyncComp.php thats it

Comment: Can you Post it as answer... what Actually I have to do.. Coz i am new to PHP and not able to get it

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. While their are options you can pass to curl to allow things (`--post301` and `--post302`), no browser supports being told to do a redirect via POST.

You will need to do this via a form and javascript instead. Something like:

```
<form action="<?= url_money.'SyncComp.php' ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="Comp" value="YES" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">document.forms[0].submit();</script>
<?php die(); ?>
```

Comment: But.. The page gets called.. its exexcutes its work and in the end makes the redirect

Comment: Yes, but you can't make that redirect a POST without using a form. The form I provided is to be used after the page does all its work, instead of doing a `Location` redirect.

Comment: This much script will be the header . I just have to replace it with my header..After my php gets executed.. this will run after that