# How to redirect with POST data

Tags: php, html, redirect, post, get

The following code will let me redirect the page to a new location, and take the `GET` variables with me..

```
<?php
// set GET variables
$name="John";
$email="me@there.com"
// redirect the page
header("Location: ../process.php?name=$name&email=$email");
?>
```

How can I do exactly the same thing and take `POST` variables with me?

I need to do this to simulate another page that has a form and submit button on it. Normally, on that page, the user would press the submit button and the `POST` data would be sent to `process.php`. I need my new page, after performing some processing, to re-direct to `process.php` with the `POST` data. This needs to happen without anyone pressing a button.

I can't use sessions, as the page I am simulating does not do this - it just sends the `POST` data when the submit button is pressed.

I can't use javascript as there is no-user interaction to press a button - it is purely a program-branch that will cause this to happen.

I don't mind using curl or JQuery, but haven't been able to figure out how to do it from the code I have already found. I would be very grateful for a working example, please.

Comment: There's also this question: [PHP Redirection with Post Parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865289/php-redirection-with-post-parameters). According to the accepted answer to that question, it's not possible from the server.

Comment: Hi - this is not a duplicate. I have read those answers and they do not answer my question. I have seen some posts that say this can be done cURL, but I can't get it to work. If anyone knows how to do it in this way, please reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code.

```
<form name="myForm" id="submit" action="test.php" method="POST">
    <p>
        <input name="name" value="John" />
         <input name="email" value="me@there.com" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#submit").submit();
});
</script>
```