# Show the final redirect headers using curl

Tags: curl

The curl command:

```
curl -IL "http://www.bbc.co.uk"
```

returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
X-BBC-No-Scheme-Rewrite: 1
X-Cache-Action: HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 18686
Vary: X-BBC-Edge-Scheme
Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600
X-Cache-Age: 2624
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Thu, 02 Nov 2017 16:55:53 GMT
Location: https://www.bbc.co.uk/
Content-Length: 178
Connection: Keep-Alive

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
ETag: W/"3fdf4-XNfGeb/Aqcmv8OYZKVQdoUFYC34"
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 261620
Date: Thu, 02 Nov 2017 16:55:53 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: BBC-UID=65699f7bb41e91e9d7e103d8618f7780367bf9e637843476ca70678244f407000curl/7.19.7%20(x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)%20libcurl/7.19.7%20NSS/3.19.1%20Basic%20ECC%20zlib/1.2.3%20libidn/1.18%20libssh2/1.4.2; expires=Mon, 01-Nov-21 16:55:53 GMT; path=/; domain=.bbc.co.uk
X-Cache-Action: HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 5
X-Cache-Age: 0
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Vary: Accept-Encoding, X-CDN, X-BBC-Edge-Scheme
```

(In production, I use `-i` and not `-I` to get the whole payload)

How do I get curl to hide the preceding header(s) that issue the redirect, and just return the header of the final target resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such an option in `curl`, but this simple `sed` program is all you need:

```
sed '/^HTTP\/1.1 3[0-9][0-9]/,/^\r$/d' file
```

If you pipe your `curl` output through it, it will delete (notice the [`d` action](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Text_002c-deleting) at the end) all header blocks that start with any `3xx` redirection code (`HTTP/1.1 3[0-9][0-9]`) and end with an empty line (an empty line in Unix is actually `\n` only, recognized in `sed` with `^$` pattern, but HTTP headers use DOS newline sequence `\r\n`, which after stripping by `sed` becomes `\r`; so we have to match `^\r$`). To select a range of lines, `sed` [range addressing](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Range-Addresses) is used with [regexp addresses](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Regexp-Addresses).

---

For your example:

```
$ curl -sIL "http://www.bbc.co.uk" | sed '/^HTTP\/1.1 3[0-9][0-9]/,/^\r$/d'
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
ETag: W/"3fbed-SZN5fj1ugmv3uhAJWfQBrAvzK1M"
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 261101
Date: Thu, 02 Nov 2017 22:53:19 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: BBC-UID=95994f2b2a4bf...57f26d5442240curl/7.50.1; expires=Mon, 01-Nov-21 22:53:19 GMT; path=/; domain=.bbc.co.uk
X-Cache-Action: HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 649
X-Cache-Age: 119
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Vary: Accept-Encoding, X-CDN, X-BBC-Edge-Scheme
```

Similarly for the complete response (with body):

```
$ curl -siL "http://www.bbc.co.uk" | sed '/^HTTP\/1.1 3[0-9][0-9]/,/^\r$/d'
```

Notice the `-s` flag we used above to suppress `curl`'s progress output.

Comment: Word of warning to anyone who reads this (spent last 2 hours on this!) if using POST, curl will only send the data payload to the first URL.  The redirect URLs will only be GETs (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802582/php-redirection-with-code-307-changes-method-from-post-to-get)

Comment: Yes, it says exactly so in the [`-L` docs](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-L).