# Posting Form Data to Redirect Page

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect

I have a contact form that I'm using phpmailer to send out the information that was entered in the form and once sent is redirected to another page. Which works great, now what I would like is to have all the information that is sent to the email address also posted on the redirect page (ie - target.php). I use 3 pages 1 for html, 1 for verify(js) and 1 (phpmailer) to send. I have read other questions here and I know if you put the redirect page in the action"target.php" on the form you can get the data, except I have to put action"appt.php" which is my phpmailer form. I have tried:

```
 <body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Form data</h2>
        <hr/>
        <p>This is a simple page showing the data you have just submitted</p>
        <?php
        $fullnameField = $_POST['fullname'];
        echo $fullnameField;
        $addressField = $_POST['address'];
        echo $addressField;
        ?>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

I put the code above on the target.php page.

This is what I get when redirected to target.php page:

Notice: Undefined index: fullname in C:\xampp\htdocs\appt\target.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: address in C:\xampp\htdocs\appt\target.php on line 16

Also tried taking off Field at the end of the $ and still get the same code.

Here is html page:

```
<form id="defaultForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="appt.php">
   <fieldset>

  <!-- Form Name -->
  <legend>Appointment Request</legend>

  <!-- Full Name -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Full Name*</label>
    <div class="col-md-6  inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
        <input  name="fullname" placeholder="Your Full Name" class="form-control"  type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Address -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >Address*</label>
    <div class="col-md-6  inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-road"></i></span>
        <input name="address" placeholder="Your Address" class="form-control"  type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- City -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">City*</label>
    <div class="col-md-6  inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></span>
        <input name="city" placeholder="Your City" class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- State Select -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">State*</label>
    <div class="col-md-6 selectContainer">
      <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
        <select name="state" class="form-control selectpicker" >
          <option value=" " >Please select your state</option>
          <option>Ohio</option>
          <option>Pennsylvania</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Zip Code -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Zip Code*</label>
    <div class="col-md-6  inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i></span>
        <input name="zip" placeholder="Your Zip Code" class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Phone Number -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Phone*</label>
    <div class="col-md-6  inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
        <input name="phone" placeholder="(330)123-1234" class="form-control"  type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Email -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-mail*</label>
    <div class="col-md-6  inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
        <input name="email" placeholder="Your Email Address" class="form-control"  type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Appt Reason Select -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Appt Reason*</label>
    <div class="col-md-6 selectContainer">
      <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
        <select name="reason" class="form-control selectpicker" >
         <option value=" ">Select Your Appointment Reason</option>
         <option>Roofing</option>
         <option>Siding</option>
         <option>Doors</option>
         <option>Windows</option>
         <option>Decking</option>
         <option>Comfort Rooms</option>
         <option>Kitchen</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Appt Date -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Appt Date*</label>
    <div class="col-md-6  inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
        <input name="apptDate" placeholder="Date You Would Like Appt" class="form-control"  type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Appt Time-->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Appt Time*</label>
    <div class="col-md-6  inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group date" id="timepicker"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
        <input name="apptTime" placeholder="Time You Would Like Appt" class="form-control"  type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Contact Method Select -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Contact You*</label>
    <div class="col-md-6 selectContainer">
      <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
        <select name="method" class="form-control selectpicker" >
         <option value=" ">Select Your Contact Method</option>
         <option>Email</option>
         <option>Phone</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <!-- Project Description -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Project Description*</label>
    <div class="col-md-6  inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Project Description" rows="5"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Captcha -->

  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Captcha</label>
      <div class="col-md-6 inputGroupContainer">
       <div id="captchaContainer"></div>
     </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Button -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Send <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
    </div>
  </div>

 </fieldset>
</form>
```

appt.php (phpmailer form):

```
 <?php
session_start();
/**
 * This example shows settings to use when sending via Google's Gmail servers.
 */

//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');   

//Contact Form Data
$fullnameField = $_POST['fullname'];
$addressField = $_POST['address'];
$cityField = $_POST['city'];
$stateField = $_POST['state'];
$zipcodeField = $_POST['zip'];
$phoneField = $_POST['phone'];
$emailField = $_POST['email'];
$apptReasonField = $_POST['reason'];
$apptDateField = $_POST['apptDate'];
$apptTimeField = $_POST['apptTime'];
$methodField = $_POST['method'];
$commentsField = $_POST['comment'];

require 'mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer();

//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();

//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.aol.com';
// use
// $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
// if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6

//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587;

//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "username";

//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "password";

//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('sent from');

//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('sent to');

//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'Information For Appointment Wanted';

//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->Body = <<<EOD
<br><p>Here is the information $fullnameField entered in your Appointment form.</p>
<br><hr><br>
<b>Name:</b>&nbsp; $fullnameField<hr><br>
<b>Address:</b>&nbsp; $addressField<hr><br>
<b>City:</b>&nbsp; $cityField<hr><br>
<b>State:</b>&nbsp; $stateField<hr><br>
<b>Zip Code:</b>&nbsp; $zipcodeField<hr><br>
<b>Phone #:</b>&nbsp; $phoneField<hr><br>
<b>E-mail:</b>&nbsp; $emailField<hr><br>
<b>Appointment Reason:</b>&nbsp; $apptReasonField<hr><br>
<b>Date Wanted For Appointment:</b>&nbsp; $apptDateField<hr><br>
<b>Time Wanted For Appointment:</b>&nbsp; $apptTimeField<hr><br>
<b>Best Way To Contact You:</b>&nbsp; $methodField<hr><br>
<b>Project Description:</b>&nbsp; $commentsField<hr><br>
EOD;


//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

//send the message, check for errors
if(!$mail->Send())
{
 echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}else{

$_SESSION[fullname]=$fullnameField; 
$_SESSION[address]=$addressField; 
$_SESSION[city]=$cityField;
$_SESSION[state]=$stateField; 
$_SESSION[zip]=$zipcodeField; 
$_SESSION[phone]=$phoneField;
$_SESSION[email]=$emailField; 
$_SESSION[reason]=$apptReasonField; 
$_SESSION[apptDate]=$apptDateField;
$_SESSION[apptTime]=$apptTimeField;
$_SESSION[method]=$methodField;
$_SESSION[comment]=$commentsField;

     header('Location: http://localhost/appt/target.php');

}
```

Here is the target.php

```
    <?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Thank You</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <p class="thank">Thank you <b><?php echo $_SESSION['fullname']; ?></b> for scheduling an appointment with U.S. Pride Home Specialists. We will be contacting you by the contact method you chose as soon as possible.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div><div class="col-md-8">Your Appointment Form Information</div><div class="col-md-2"></div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div><div class="col-md-8"><b>Name:</b> <?php echo $_SESSION['fullname']; ?></div><div class="col-md-2"></div>
        </div>
        <hr>        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div><div class="col-md-8"><b>Address:</b> <?php echo $_SESSION['address']; ?></div><div class="col-md-2"></div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div><div class="col-md-8"><b>City:</b> <?php echo $_SESSION['city']; ?></div><div class="col-md-2"></div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div><div class="col-md-8"><b>State:</b> <?php echo $_SESSION['state']; ?></div><div class="col-md-2"></div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div><div class="col-md-8"><b>Zip Code:</b> <?php echo $_SESSION['zip']; ?></div><div class="col-md-2"></div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div><div class="col-md-8"><b>Phone:</b> <?php echo $_SESSION['phone']; ?></div><div class="col-md-2"></div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div><div class="col-md-8"><b>E-mail:</b> <?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?></div><div class="col-md-2"></div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div><div class="col-md-8"><b>Appointment Reason:</b> <?php echo $_SESSION['reason']; ?></div><div class="col-md-2"></div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div><div class="col-md-8"><b>Appointment Date Wanted:</b> <?php echo $_SESSION['apptDate']; ?></div><div class="col-md-2"></div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div><div class="col-md-8"><b>Appointment Time Wanted:</b> <?php echo $_SESSION['apptTime']; ?></div><div class="col-md-2"></div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div><div class="col-md-8"><b>Way You Wanted Contacted:</b> <?php echo $_SESSION['method']; ?></div><div class="col-md-2"></div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2"></div><div class="col-md-8"><b>Project Description:</b> <?php echo $_SESSION['comment']; ?></div><div class="col-md-2"></div>
        </div>          
    </div>
<?php
// remove all session variables
session_unset(); 

// destroy the session 
session_destroy();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865289/php-redirection-with-post-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store your form data in a database table or session for persistence.
something like:

```
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

//send the message, check for errors
if(!$mail->Send())
{
 echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}else{
    // BUILD $form_data here
    $_SESSION['temp_form_data'] = serialize($form_data); 
    and after redirect just get data from session.
    header('Location: http://localhost/appt/target.php');
}
```

And in the page that you show after redirect
in `target.php`

```
$form_data = unserialize($_SESSION['temp_form_data']);
    // Use form data here
```

Another option would be to store it in database and retrieve it after redirect.

I do not suggest placing form data params and values over a url.

Comment: I'm not sure where you are wanting me to put $_SESSION[...]etc then put $form_data = ....

Comment: I added everything like you said, once redirected this is what I got: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function deserialize() in C:\xampp\htdocs\appt\target.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\appt\target.php on line 14

Comment: @user1236784 i corrected the function name. See edit

Comment: I must be doing something wrong got Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\appt\target.php on line 16. I even tried adding session(); at top of both pages.

Comment: @user1236784 you start the session with `session_start();` , both file must have this to work. Also it must be `$_SESSION` not `_SESSION`

Comment: Ok I added session_start(); at the top of my appt.php page and on the target.php page I have html first then <?php session_start(); the code you said ?> and when I submit form and redirect only thing that is on page is This is a simple page showing the data you have just submitted which is the html on that page.

Comment: `session_start();` must be the first thing in your php files. Please follow documentation form php.net http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: I have looked at that page that's why I added session_start(); to each page. I added the target.php page so you can see what I have and also the appt.php was edited.

Comment: you have to build the `$form_data`

Comment: Ok so I'm not sure on that, but is this what it should look like $form_data = array('fullnameField' => $fullname, 'addressField' => $address, (and so forth)  ); and would I put this at the top of appt.php page?

Comment: It would be better in the `else` right before you assign the value to session.

Comment: I appreciate your help I'm lost when it comes to arrays and then posting to another page.

Comment: Practice makes perfect. Keep going. Those errors will help you learn

Comment: I got things working, updated everything up top. Thank you for all the help.