# why does my php redirects me to my index.php page even though i didn't put any instructions to do it?

Tags: php

here is my code. it is for the removal of any borrower. when the process was successful it supposedly proceeds to the books.php but instead, it goes to my index page

```
 <?php
    if (isset($_POST['return'])) {
        require 'include.dbh.php';
        $id = $_POST['return'];
        $sqlr = "DELETE FROM borrower WHERE id=" . $id;
        echo $sqlr;
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sqlr)) {
            header("Location: ../books.php?borrowedbookhasbeenreturned");
            exit();
        } else {
            header("Location ../books.php?error=connectionerror");
            exit();
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
    } else {
        header("Location: ../books.php");
    }
?>
```

---

and this is the code for my book.php and also I'm a beginner on PHP. when the button is clicked it sends the id of the borrower to code above then it would do its thing. well it works but it didn't redirect me to the page where it should be instead it redirects me to the index.php

---

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
        header("Location: ../login.php");
    } else if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    } else {
        $butt = $_POST['submit'];
        require 'php/include.dbh.php';
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM bookinfo WHERE btitle='" . $butt . "'";
        if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {

            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $ID = $row['bid'];
                $bookname = $row['btitle'];
                $desc = $row['bdesc'];
                $q = $row['quantity'];
                $img = $row['imgpath'];
            }

            /*freeresultset*/
            $result->free();
        }
    }
    ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/up.css">
     <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.jpg">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 </head>

 <body>
     <div class="content">
         <div class="header">
             <table class="heading">
                 <tr>
                     <td>
                         <span class="title">Seshat</span>
                         <span class="tag"> | a faster way to record books</span>
                     </td>
                     <td style="text-align: right;">
                         <span class="title">Book Details</span>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
             </table>
             <hr>

             <div class="cheader">Book Details</div>
             <div class="cbody">
                 <div class="booktitle">
                     <table>
                         <tr>
                             <td>
                                 <label for="">Title: </label>
                                 <span><?php echo $bookname; ?></span>
                             </td>
                             <td>
                                 <label for="">Book ID:</label>
                                 <span name="bid"><?php echo $ID; ?></span>
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                     </table>
                 </div>
                 <hr>
                 <div>
                     <label for="">total quantity: </label>
                     <span><?php echo $q; ?></span>
                 </div>
                 <br>
                 <div class="description">
                     <label for="">Description </label>
                     <div>
                         <p>
                             <?php
                                echo $desc;
                                ?>
                         </p>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="buttons">
                     <div onclick="show()" id="s" name="borrow">Borrow</div>
                     <form action="php/include.discard.php" method="POST">
                         <button value="<?php echo $bookname; ?>" type="submit" name="discard"
                             title="Delete this Book">Discard</button>
                     </form>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="cheader">Book Details</div>
             <div class="cbody">
                 <form action="php/include.return.php" method="POST">
                     <div class="users">
                         <table border="1">
                             <thead>
                                 <td id="asize">Book ID</td>
                                 <td id="asize">Name</td>
                                 <td id="asize">Grade And Section</td>
                                 <td id="asize">LRN</td>
                                 <td id="asize">Borrowed date</td>
                                 <td id="asize">Date Of expected return</td>
                                 <td id="asize" class="v">Actions</td>
                             </thead>

                             <!-- ----------------------------------- -->

                             <?php
                                $sqlb = "SELECT * FROM borrower where gid='" . $butt . "'";
                                if ($result = $conn->query($sqlb)) {
                                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                        $field1name = $row["bid"];
                                        $field2name = $row["fname"] . " " . $row["lname"];
                                        $field3name = $row["grade"] . " - " . $row["section"];
                                        $field4name = $row["lrn"];
                                        $field5name = $row["dob"];
                                        $field6name = $row["der"];
                                        $id = $row['id'];
                                        echo '<tr> 
                                            <td>' . $field1name . '</td> 
                                            <td>' . $field2name . '</td> 
                                            <td>' . $field3name . '</td> 
                                            <td>' . $field4name . '</td> 
                                            <td>' . $field5name . '</td> 
                                            <td>' . $field6name . '</td> 
                                            <td><button type="submit" name="return" value="' . $id . '" class="edit" title="return the books">Return</button></td>
                                        </tr>';
                                    }
                                    $result->free();
                                }
                                ?>

                             <!-- ------------------------------------------- -->

                         </table>
                     </div>
                 </form>
             </div>
             <br>
             <hr><br>
             <div id="f">
                 <div class="cheader">Borrow Form</div>
                 <div class="cbody" id="form">
                     <span style="margin:20pt 20pt;">Student</span>
                     <form class="" action="php/include.book.php" method="post">

                         <div class="student">
                             <table class="formt">
                                 <tr>
                                     <td>
                                         <span>First Name</span>
                                         <br>
                                         <input id="nem" type="text" name="fn" value="">
                                     </td>
                                     <td>
                                         <span>Last Name</span>
                                         <br>
                                         <input type="text" name="ln" value="">
                                     </td>
                                     <td>
                                         <span>Grade And Section</span><br>
                                         <input style="width:30%;" name="g" type="number" placeholder="Grade" value="">
                                         <input style="width:50%;" type="text" placeholder="Section" name="s" value="">
                                     </td>
                                     <td>
                                         <span style="font-size:10pt">Learner's Reference Number</span>
                                         <br>
                                         <input type="text" name="lrn" value="">
                                     </td>
                                 </tr>
                             </table>
                         </div>
                         <span style="margin:20pt 20pt;">Book</span>
                         <div class="student">
                             <table class="formt">
                                 <tr>
                                     <td>
                                         <span>Book ID</span>
                                         <br>
                                         <input type="text" name="bid">
                                     </td>
                                     <td>
                                         <span style="font-size: 8pt;">Date of Borrowing and the day of expected
                                             return</span>
                                         <br>
                                         <input type="date" name="dob" style="width:40%;">
                                         <input type="date" name="der" style="width:40%;">
                                     </td>
                                 </tr>
                             </table>
                         </div>
                         <br>
                         <div class="buttons">
                             <button type="submit" <?php echo "value='" . $butt . "'"; ?> name="submit">Submit</button>
                             <button type="reset">Reset</button>
                         </div>
                 </div>
                 </form>
             </div>
             <div id="last">
                 <form action="php/include.book.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                     <div id="bt" class="buttons">
                         <button type="submit" name="back">Back to Main</button>
                     </div>
                 </form>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     function show() {

         if (document.getElementById("f").style.height < "384px") {
             document.getElementById("f").style.transition = ".5s";
             document.getElementById("f").style.height = "384px";
             document.getElementById("f").style.opacity = "1";
             document.getElementById("s").innerHTML = "Close";
             document.getElementById("bt").style.top = "0pt";
         } else {
             document.getElementById("f").style.transition = ".5s";
             document.getElementById("f").style.height = "0px";
             document.getElementById("f").style.display = "0";
             document.getElementById("s").innerHTML = "Borrow";
             document.getElementById("bt").style.top = "-20pt";


         }
     }
     </script>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: Btw, don't simply append `$id` to the end of the query. That makes you vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Relative URLs `../books.php?borrowedbookhasbeenreturned` ?

Comment: What happens if you put complete absolute URLs? Never used header() with relative URLs though. Also, you are a missing a `:` in one of your headers().

Comment: Can you post the code for books.php?

Comment: header("Location: ../books.php?borrowedbookhasbeenreturned");

This is not valid PHP. You need to pass a parameter in your URL. What param does the "borrowedbookhasbeenreturned" value relate to?

Comment: @RussJ there the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`header("Location: ../books.php?borrowedbookhasbeenreturned")` 
(though not valid) is the problem.

You are not setting `$_POST['submit']`, so this will trigger the following section of the code

```
} else if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

When using the header you are not sending any POST data. so the `$_POST['submit'] is not set, and the above logic will always be true.

Check this for possible solutions [PHP Redirection with Post Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865289/php-redirection-with-post-parameters)